# Laravel, call many artisan commands with progress bar output

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have created a simple trait to generate a progress bar during command executions.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    trait ProgressBarOutput
    {
        public function runProcess(\Countable $countable, callable $callback)
        {
            $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($countable));
            $bar->start();
            foreach ($countable as $item) {
                call_user_func($callback, $item);
                $bar->advance();
            }
            $bar->finish();
            $this->line('');
        }
    }
```

That works, inside my command page:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Console\Commands\ProgressBarOutput;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MigrateUsers extends Command
{
    use ProgressBarOutput;

    protected $signature = 'migrate:users';
    protected $description = 'Migrate users table from old to new';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info("users");
        $rows = \DB::connection('old')->table('users')->get();
        $this->runProcess($rows, function($row) {
            \DB::connection('mysql')->table('users')->insert([
                'id' => $row->id,
                'name' => $row->name,
                'surname' => $row->surname,
            ]);
        });

        $this->info("cars");
        $rows = \DB::connection('old')->table('cars')->get();
        $this->runProcess($rows, function($row) {
            \DB::connection('mysql')->table('cars')->insert([
                'id' => $row->id,
                'model' => $row->model,
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to split these micro imports into separate files then merge together:

```
public function handle()
{
    \Artisan::call("migrate:users");
    \Artisan::call("migrate:cars");
}
```

The commands get correctly called, but no output is printed nor a progress bar.
Have you ever faced this kind of problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`migrate` command need the user to confirm the process to continue. Adding `--no-interaction` along with the call will remove all user interactions. In this example it will be like,

```
public function handle()
{
    \Artisan::call("migrate:users --no-interaction");
    \Artisan::call("migrate:cars --no-interaction");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I wrote "migrate" because I am migrating from a database to another one, but I could call it "app:users". In any case, the progress bar is printed at once the process has been completed and not during its execution.

Comment: Also, if I call "migrate:users" as a single command, the progress bar gets filled little by little and correctly. If I run "migrate:all" which contains all the commands, the progress bar is printed only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Just call $this->call("your-command"); instead of \Artisan::call("your-command");

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->call("migrate:users");
    $this->call("migrate:cars");
}
```